# Cannot pass arguments via swift function

Tags: swift, function, arguments, parameter-passing

This problem came up trying to run macOS commands within a swift file. I'm having some issues passing arguments into functions using Swift. When I run the lines within the function `date` outside of the function definition, things work just fine. I'm not able to see any errors within Xcode. As a Swift newbie, any advise is appreciated!

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

//Command arguments
let dateLocation = "/bin/date"
let format = "+DATE: %Y-%m-%d%nTIME: %H:%M:%S"
let command = Process()

//Command function with arguments
func date(args: String) -> String {
    command.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dateLocation)
    command.arguments = [args]
    try command.run()
}

//Run function
date(args: format)
```

Comment: I see two errors here, not sure why they're not showing up in Xcode. `try command.run()` can `throw`, but you don't catch that error, but you also don't propagate it along, either (since `date(args:)` isn't marked `throws`). Also, your function declares that it returns `String`, but has no `return` statement. In any case, why not just use the built-in `Date` and `DateFormatter`, rather than launching an external process like this?

Comment: Thanks for the information @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, I really appreciate it. I am using an external process in this example to build upon running macOS binaries to read information within a Swift app UI. Some system information (to my knowledge) can only be accessed via macOS binary files. I am incredibly new to Swift so I thought I’d reach out to see if I could lend some knowledge from the community.

Comment: Well welcome to Swift, and SO! If your question involves a simplified example of a use case, you should mention that. Otherwise people will point you towards saner ways of doing the same thing you show (getting some time information).  "Some system information (to my knowledge) can only be accessed via macOS binary files" Like which?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your function is declared to return a string but doesn't return anything and secondly you are calling a function that can throw an error which you correctly handles by using `try` but you need to either handle any possible error or throw it from your function. Here I chosed the later in my example by adding `throws` to the declaration

```
func date(args: String) throws {
    command.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dateLocation)
    command.arguments = [args]
    try command.run()
}
```

Now you can call your function and catch any error like below

```
do {
    try date(args: format)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Output:

> DATE: 2020-03-31
>   TIME: 18:50:25